# Using parallel processing for Point3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am working on a morph target animation.

I am trying to find ways of speeding up some calculations of mesh points in 3D WPF.

So I have two meshes - a 'current' mesh which holds the state of play and a 'morph' mesh which I need to calculate the differences between.

I'm trying to use a parallel for loop, but it keeps throwing an error :

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WindowsBase.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: One or more errors occurred.
>
> The program '[7444] HelixTrial.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1
>   (0xffffffff).

My code is pretty simple. It makes a list, counts the positions in the current mesh (which is equal to the target morph mesh). Then it loops over the meshes finding the difference in positions via a Vector3D. It should then add the vector to the list.

```
List<Vector3D> listVectors = new List<Vector3D>();
int i = currentMesh.Positions.Count;

Parallel.For(0, i, thisloop =>
{
     Point3D mor = morphMesh.Positions[thisloop];
     Point3D cur = currentMesh.Positions[thisloop];
     Vector3D foo = mor - cur;
     listVectors.Add(foo);
});
```

It looks okay to me, but does not work. Is it possible that one cannot use Point3D in a parallel loop ?

Many thanks.

**EDIT**

This is meant to show how 'morphMesh' is made and where it comes from.

morphMesh is taken from a group in a morph target for my human model (imported .OBJ format). I am only animating parts of the mesh. So I get the group of the mesh I am interested in by grabbing the child of the morph target model.

```
var lipsmorph = morph.Children[21];
morphgeometry = (GeometryModel3D)lipsmorph;
morphMesh = (MeshGeometry3D)morphgeometry.Geometry;
```

So what that is doing is getting the lips group of the morph target model, this being identified as the group in the child index of 21. Then it turns that into a mesh so that I can use it calculate coordinate differences and manipulate the corresponding mesh in the live 'current' model. I also use weights too but I have tried to keep my example code to the minimum to first get it working with mesh differences. The weights are simple maths so should not present as much of a problem as what I am asking here.

**EDIT TWO**

Using Scott's code and freezing the models first - this will work. But for me this is not worth pursuing as running this code takes the same time as the non parallel solution does for all my calculations such as the weights. Scott alluded to that in one of his comments. I'm just not doing enough maths to make a difference.

But anyway, maybe for other people's reference I will post the code that finally stopped throwing errors.

```
i = currentMesh.Positions.Count;
List<Vector3D> listVectors = new List<Vector3D>();
morphMesh.Freeze();
currentMesh.Freeze();

try
{
    Parallel.For(0, i,
    () => new List<Vector3D>(), //Create a thread local list per thread
    (thisloop, loopstate, localList) => //"localList" is the variable we created above or was the list that was returned from a previous loop iteration.
    {
        Point3D mor = morphMesh.Positions[thisloop];
        Point3D cur = currentMesh.Positions[thisloop];
        Vector3D foo = mor - cur;
        localList.Add(foo);
        return localList; //This hands the list off to be the input "localList" variable for the next thread that uses it.
    },
    localList => //Combine the thread local lists in to the master list in a thread safe way.
    {
        lock (listVectors)
            listVectors.AddRange(localList);
    });
}
catch (AggregateException b)
{
    data.Text = b.InnerException.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Not a answer to your question but I recommend you pick up the free book from Microsoft ["Patterns for Parallel Programming"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) many of the code examples in it revolves around 3D processing and it will give you good guidelines on how much work you should be doing in your `Parallel.For` loop.

Answer (score 2):

`listVectors` is not thread safe so you can not be accessing it from multiple threads. You must either use thread local objects or a thread safe collection when working with the list.

Here is a thread local version using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Parallel.For`.

```
int i = currentMesh.Positions.Count;
List<Vector3D> listVectors = new List<Vector3D>();

Parallel.For(0, i, 
    () => new List<Vector3D>(), //Create a thread local list per thread
    (thisloop, loopstate, localList)  => //"localList" is the variable we created above or was the list that was returned from a previous loop iteration.
    {
         Point3D mor = morphMesh.Positions[thisloop];
         Point3D cur = currentMesh.Positions[thisloop];
         Vector3D foo = mor - cur;
         localList.Add(foo);
         return localList; //This hands the list off to be the input "localList" variable for the next thread that uses it.
    },
    localList => //Combine the thread local lists in to the master list in a thread safe way.
    {
        lock(listVectors)
            listVectors.AddRange(localList);
    });
```

However as I was alluding to in the comment I made in your question, I think you may not be doing enough work inside your loop and some of the overhead costs may be hurting the potential performance. Look [at the book](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) I recommended and specifically look at "TOO FINE-GRAINED, TOO COARSE GRAINED" example anti-pattern on page 28.

Comment: There is actually a little more work to do, it will need to calculate weights too, but it's not a huge amount more. I already timed the non parallel code I have, so I will be able to compare the two methods for speed. And thanks I will certainly have a read of your recommendations.

Comment: This code is generating errors : A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you wrote I can't tell you (please edit your original question with the new code examples. You need to look at the `Message` property of the inner exceptions of the `AggregateException`'s. They will tell you what went wrong. Check the box for "[Break on thrown exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)" so your debugger will stop on a exception even if there is no `try/catch`

Comment: Well it is WPF, and usually you can't access such properties on a separate thread.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa I am betting that is what it is too, but without knowing what the types of `morphMesh` and `currentMesh` are we can't say for sure.

Comment: OK that's food for thought. I will pull this code out of my project for now in case something else is interfering. I will do a standalone example with two meshes. For now as you were asking about the meshes I  will add the code for that above for now.

Comment: You can try morphMesh.Freeze() and currentMesh.Freeze() to see if it helps.

Comment: OK, but first...the error thrown by Scott's code is System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: That worked. I'd have to Clone the currentMesh first so I can still edit it, but it does work. I am however giving up on this as this is no faster than the regular solution. I have added the up to date details to the original topic. If nothing else I learnt a lot about threads and error checking.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, you are not doing enough work inside the `Parallel.For` to make it worth the overhead. What do you do with `listVectors` when you are done, can you do some of that work inside the `PArallel.For` too?

Comment: I might be able to yes. The code I have given here is only one stage of the calculations. I have to apply weights and do a bit more maths. I'll give it a go today.

Answer (score 1):

use linq's AsParallel:

```
listVectors.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, currentMesh.Positions.Count)
   .AsParallel()
   .Select(thisloop => morphMesh.Positions[thisloop] - currentMesh.Positions[thisloop]));
```

Comment: I don't know if this will really make it parallel or not. At the very list I think the `.Select()` must come after the `.AsParallel()` to get any benefits.

Comment: K, you don't need the `.ToList()` since it's already an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Scott so you only need need the `.AsParallel` to be right after `.Range`.

Comment: Yes, and you have it as `.Range(...).Select(...).AsParallel()` I think it needs to be `.Range(...).AsParallel().Select(...)`

Comment: `List<Vector3D> listVectors = new List<Vector3D>();

                    Parallel.For(0, i, thisloop =>
                    {
                        listVectors.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, currentMesh.Positions.Count)
                        .AsParallel()
                        .Select(x => morphMesh.Positions[thisloop] - currentMesh.Positions[thisloop]));
                    });`

Comment: The above comment is the code I am using, not sure I did that right. I'm getting errors : A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @Rog you are using it incorrectly. Some1Pro0's code is totally replacing the `Parallel.For` you don't use it at all with his code. Everything you have in your original example is replaced with what is posted in this example.

Comment: OK, I don't know how to account for the 'thisloop' variable then. How is that being incremented please ? If I just replace my loop with that code the 'thisloop' variable is underlined red and it comments that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Rog he had a error in his example, I have corrected it. It should make more sense now. The `x` in his example should have been `thisloop` (or the `thisloop`'s should have been `x`'s)

Comment: OK that's generating errors. A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Comment: The AggregateException Message only says "One or more errors occured"... As it was mentioned in the other example, could this be down to using WPF ?

Comment: Look at `InnerException` property.

Comment: I cannot post it all but I guess the first line is the one to look at : System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Media.Media3D.MeshGeometry3D.get_Positions()
   at HelixTrial.MainWindow.<>c__DisplayClass4.<morphTheModel>b__2(Int32 thisloop) in c:\Users\Roger\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HelixTrial P\HelixTrial\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 658................